# Running Client's method from Client's invoked method in server

Tags: c#, signalr

The logic:
1. There is some method running in the Client app (lets say clientMethod1)
2. In the middle of clientMethod1, it Invokes a method in server (lets say serverMethod)
3. While serverMethod is doing it's job, at some point it should also invoke another method in the Client (lets say clientMethod2)

**pseudocode**

CLIENT SIDE:

```
clientMethod1
{
 something...
 something...
 Hub.Invoke(serverMethod);
 something...
}

public clientMethod2
{
 something...
}
```

SERVER SIDE:

```
public serverMethod
{
 something...
 something..
 Client.(id).clientMethod2();
 something..
 something...
}
```

Hope it makes sense.

**Question**
Is this scenario possible? I could not manage the server-side method to "invoke" the client's method, while the server method itself is being called from Client...

Comment: of coz its possible.

Comment: @Mark any example?

Comment: There are a lot of examples out there if you have more efforts to search it. If you have tried something and find a problem, you can come back Here and We will help you.